# Bottom Navigation Bar Design in Dotnet Maui

Tags: xaml, maui

I am working on a design for Dotnet Maui but not able to achieve the depth as per design.

[image]

I have tried box frame but was not been able to achieve the top shadow and circle cut. I have also created this as a floating button.

### ContentPage

Grid ->

```
<HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        
        <Grid RowDefinitions="22,15" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="28,20,10,0">
            
            <ImageButton Source="homeicon.svg"
                     WidthRequest="20"
                     HeightRequest="22"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Home"
                   FontFamily="WorkSansRegular"
                   FontSize="12"
                   />
        </Grid>
        
        <Grid RowDefinitions="22,15" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="28,20,10,0">
            <ImageButton Source="wallet.svg"
                     WidthRequest="20"
                     HeightRequest="22"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Wallet"
                   FontFamily="WorkSansRegular"
                   FontSize="12"
                   />
        </Grid>
        <Ellipse Margin="16,-15,0,0"
                             Fill="#AFAFAF"                             
                             StrokeThickness="4"
                             WidthRequest="70"
                             HeightRequest="70"
                             HorizontalOptions="Start"
                             VerticalOptions="Start"
                            
                 />
        <ImageButton Source="centericon.svg"
                     WidthRequest="60"
                     HeightRequest="62"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"                         
                     Margin="-65,-15,0,0"
                     />
            
        
        <Grid RowDefinitions="22,15" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="28,20,0,0">
            <ImageButton Source="activityicon.svg"
                     WidthRequest="20"
                     HeightRequest="22"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Activity" FontFamily="WorkSansRegular"
                   FontSize="12"
                   />
        </Grid>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="22,15" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="28,20,0,0">
            <ImageButton Source="profileicon.svg"
                     WidthRequest="20"
                     HeightRequest="22"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Profile" FontFamily="WorkSansRegular"
                   FontSize="12"
                   />
        </Grid>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

this part of the code is under

<ContentPage -> Grid ->

Comment: Show the code you have so far (that doesn't do what you want). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can refer to this case:[How to give a shadow effect to a frame in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002961/how-to-give-a-shadow-effect-to-a-frame-in-xamarin-forms). Wish it can help you.